# How to reset the selection of the screen recorder to the default?

Tags: finder, screen-capture

When I press Cmd+Shift+5, I summon the screen recording utility. It shows with a resizable curtain which portion of the screen is going to be recorded. However, that selection persists between invocations, and that is usually not what I want.

Since I know there is a way to reset Spotlight position — long Option-Press on the magnifier icon, — maybe there is a similar way to bring the Screen Recorder selection back to its factory default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it to not Remember Last Selection from the Options menu - then it will give you the crosshairs every time.

[image]

This works for both snapshot & screen recording modes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is this:

`defaults write com.apple.screencapture`

You can read what's in the defaults for screen capture:

```
% defaults read com.apple.screencapture
{
    "last-analytics-stamp" = "redacted";
    "last-selection" =     {
        Height = 1036;
        Width = 1401;
        X = 278;
        Y = 91;
    };
    "last-selection-display" = 0;
    location = "~/Desktop/Screenshots";
    "location-last" = "~/Desktop/Screenshots";
    showsClicks = 1;
    style = selection;
    target = file;
    video = 1;
)
```

Here's your ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screencapture.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>last-analytics-stamp</key>
    <real>redacted</real>
    <key>last-selection</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Height</key>
        <real>1036</real>
        <key>Width</key>
        <real>1401</real>
        <key>X</key>
        <real>278</real>
        <key>Y</key>
        <real>91</real>
    </dict>
    <key>last-selection-display</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>location</key>
    <string>~/Desktop/Screenshots</string>
    <key>location-last</key>
    <string>~/Desktop/Screenshots</string>
    <key>showsClicks</key>
    <true/>
    <key>style</key>
    <string>selection</string>
    <key>target</key>
    <string>file</string>
    <key>video</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Found some examples from this excellently written site -
https://ss64.com/osx/screencapture.html